# How do I convert array to hash, whose key is array value and value is index of the array

Tags: ruby

An array format is like following(the values won't duplicated in the array):

```
["ID", nil, "MO"]
```

I want to remove the `nil`, but the hash values should store the index in original  array. Expected result:

```
{
  "ID" => 0,
  "MO" => 2
}
```

How could I do it in an elegant way?

Comment: Which index should be used for duplicates? The first? Or should the value be an array of indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
["ID", nil, "MO"]
.each.with_index.with_object({}){|(e, i), h| h[e] = i unless e.nil?}
# => {"ID"=>0, "MO"=>2}
```

or

```
["ID", nil, "MO"]
.each.with_index.to_h.reject{|k, v| k.nil?}
# => {"ID"=>0, "MO"=>2}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Hash#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete) to remove the pair with `nil` key:

```
hash = ["ID", nil, "MO"].each_with_index.to_h
hash.delete(nil)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
["ID", nil, "MO"].each_with_index.to_h.tap { |h| h.delete(nil) }
```